# How to determine to use cached activity in GWT MVP?

Tags: gwt, caching, android-activity, gwt-mvp

I have a GWT application with MVP pattern.

I have two views in a page. Filter and Result view.

When I choose any filter, I am calling goto() to go to the current place.
This functionally works fine. But it rewrites a Filter view also.
I dont want the filter view to be re-written since I am calling goto() to go to the same place.

I am using a cachingactivity mapper. How can I use the latest activity and not rewrite the view?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many debug, I observed the following:
In CachingActivityMapper->getActivity(), the equals method returns false all the time.

So I tried to override the equals method in my place classes. But, since the equals method seems invoked in some of the other places it doesnot work.

Finally I created my own CachingActivtyManager, in which the getActivity() method calls my own isEqual() method. It worked as expected.

Thanks.